# Delete selected item from listbox with button from window form

Tags: c#, sql

I have a listbox and i want to select and item in it and press a button to delete that from the database. I can edit and save fine just not delete.

Current code:

```
private void button1_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 1)
          {
               if (listBox1.SelectedValue != null)
               {
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Item Deleted");
               }
          }
     else
     {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No ITEMS Found");
     }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: if you want to delete from the database then write database deletion code which is missing currently,

Comment: @RajatJaiswal I want this to be able to be done int he front end on a windows form

Comment: Refresh is missing in your code after delete listBox1.Refresh();

Comment: still getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 1)
          {
               if (listBox1.SelectedValue != null)
               {
                    var items = (List<YourType>)listBox1.DataSource;

                    var item = (YourType)listBox1.SelectedValue;
                    listBox1.DataSource = null;
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    items.Remove(item);
                    listBox1.DataSource = items;
               }
          }
     else
     {
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No ITEMS Found");
     }
}
```

This will work

Comment: Check now, I tested it and it worked perfectly fine. Just change yourType with your actual type, and List<> with the collection type you used at the moment of Datasource assignment.

Comment: How do i know which is YourType?

Comment: listBox1.Datasource.GetType()

Comment: where do i put that>?

Comment: Just run a piece of code to get the actual type datasource has and put a breakpoint at the moment of assignment, so that you can replace List<> with the type given at the breakpoint

Comment: Sorry im very new to c# where would i run that

Comment: Could you paste your entire code from initialization of the listbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171865/discussion-between-k1dev-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be multiple items selected on the ListBox. Below logic will remove from the UI. Also, you can add logic to remove the items from the database if required.

Below exception occurs when Data Bindings are different than data sources.

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is
>   set

A data source specifies the source of data whereas data bindings define how data is bound to once it is retrieved. Typically, data binding occurs only during UI initialisation, and it doesn't change after that.
The data source itself can change over the life of control, but this is rare.

Here, the data source elements change.

On to your actual error.  You cannot set DataSource and modify the Items property.  It isn't allowed.  The correct way to handle this is to add the items to your data source.  This insertion in your data source will cause the control to update the list automatically. The ListBox Control relies on the DS to store the data so all changes must go through that. In the rare case where you need to be able to edit the Items directly then, you'll have to do away with DataSource and manually populate the Items collection.  This update to DataSource usually is not needed though.

Below code to reset the data source

```
if(listBox1.SelectedItems != null)
{
    // Assuming its List of string
    var items = listBox1.DataSource as List<string>;  

    // Remove multiple selected items
    var count = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count;    
    while(count != 0)
    {
        var selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItems[count-1];
        if(items.ContainsKey(selectedItem))
        {
            items.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
        count--;
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.DataSource = items;
}
```

An optimised approach to store the data source and modify it to update the data source directly. Use the `ObservableCollection` type and update the collection to update the UI.

```
public class NamesClass : DependencyObject
{
   public ObservableCollection<string> Names {get; private set; }
   public TestClass()
   {
            this.Names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   }
}
```

Now include the `DependencyObject` class as DataSource and update the Names collection.

Comment: We need to understand the concept of DataBinding and DataSource. How are you setting the values in your ListBox? For above solution to work, I have assumed that it is a List of String.